# Inject style tag into html file generated by html-webpack-plugin from external sass file

Tags: webpack, sass, html-webpack-plugin

I have been wondering how to configure webpack so it would inject css from sass file into my generated html file (in style tag) without importing it into my react components. My intention is to have base css inline in the head of html and others as links.